# polygon points on sphere

Tags: geometry

I need to plot rectangular coordinates equivalent spherical coordinates on a sphere and join them later. So that it should take the form of a polygon, where can i perform this? I am not a mathematics student so I don't have an idea, how can I achieve it? I have a polygon of below mentioned coordinates on plane and i want the same polygon to be mapped/ generate/project on sphere...

The points I have to plot are mentioned below on sphere of radius 60mm

```
(-29/2,-38/2)
(29/2,-38/2)
(29/2,38/2)
(-29/2,38/2)
(-29/2,2.5)
(-10,2.5)
(-10,1.5)
(-29,1.5)
(-29/2,-1.5)
(-10,-1.5)
(-10,-2.5)
(-29/2,-2.5)
(-29/2,-38/2)
```

Comment: What are those two numbers are supposed to be? Points on a sphere in 3D have three coordinates. So what are these?

Comment: (x,y,z) and z is constant 0.05mm

Comment: If $z$ is constant (why didn't you tell us?) you are really plotting points on a circle of radius $\sqrt{60^2-0.05^2}$.  Any spreadsheet will do that.  Note that the $0.05$ does not really change anything at the accuracy of a plot.  The points you have are not on a sphere at all.

Comment: I believe OP has the projection of the points in the $x$, $y$ plane and needs to reconstruct the surface points (e.g. for the half sphere $z\ge 0$.

Comment: i need to generate a polygon varying in theta and phi direction and since radius of sphere should remains constant.. above mentioned points are rectangular coordinates

Comment: The problem has not been clear. The given points are on a sphere radius some $50$ units or so (you did not give its value ) and you want to find $(x,y,z)$ for another reduced radius value... Right?

Comment: no Sir.... i want to plot equivalent polar coordintes of mentioned cartesian coordinates on sphere

Answer (score 1):

You can use a software like [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/).

See this example:
[image: 3D scene within GeoGebra]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclGV.png))

- switch to 3D view
- add a circle with origin $(0,0,0)$ and radius $60$
- correct your view by scaling and translating such that this big object gets displayed correctly
- add the points, here I added the first three points in the $x$-$y$-plane
- use the tool for erecting a vertical (perpendicular line tool) given a point and a plane (click the point, then the $x$-$y$-plane)
- use the intersection tool to calculate the the intersection between vertical and sphere for each vertical, this will yield the points on the upper and lower half-spheres
- use the tool for drawing circle segments between three points, click the origin and then two points on the circle surface to create the arc
- then remove the helpers (e.g. verticals and unused points)

You can fiddle with this model [here](https://ggbm.at/EtuQuFuY).

The illustrated geometric operations have corresponding mathematical procedures. E.g. given a point in the $x$-$y$-plane, one can give the algebra how to calculate a vertical on paper, how to perform the intersection with the sphere etc., but my impression was you are not interested in the mathematics behind, or?

Comment: I want to generate a polygon of specified rectangular points onto surface of sphere

Comment: yes... how to get it?

Comment: in other words mapping a polygon on the sphere surface from the plane surface